# OneDrive File Picker JavaScript SDK v7.0

Tags: api, ms-office, onedrive

I can't download file to OneDrive  account, we use OneDrive File Picker JavaScript SDK v7.0 like described in the doc  (An http, https, or data URI for the file to be uploaded. OneDrive for Business and SharePoint only supports data URI values.). We create a request with date uri for pdf: data:application/pdf;base64,..... and next going the content of the file in base64. When we try to download normal files, we get the issue: "Request URI Too Large onedrive", when we download small files we can save them, but the files are empty or we can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I have not priority to comment on your question. Would you minding posting the data uri and your testing app?